# Have the authorization interceptor not intercept requests to the credentials endpoint

Tags: angular

I have an interceptor that adds a JWT access token to requests directed at a resource server:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private keycloakClientService: KeycloakClientService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return this.addAuthHeader(request, next);
  }

  private addAuthHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('=======>> Intercepting the http request to add the jwt token in the header');
  }
}
```

I also have a login form sending a request to a credentials endpoint to an authorization server:

```
  login(): void {
    this.userRestService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.authService.setJwtTokenToLocalStorage(data.token);
        this.router.navigate(['user']);
      }
    );
  }

  public login(ussername: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Sending the login credentials to obtain a token');
    const credentials = { username: ussername, password: password };
    const url: string = environment.USER_REST_URL + '/login';
    return this.httpClient.post(url, credentials);
  }
```

The problem is that the interceptor is intercepting the above request to the credentials endpoint.

I would like the interceptor to only intercept requests containing the JWT access token sent to all endpoints of the resources server but not intercept requests sent to the credentials endpoint of the authorization server.

Is there some URI pattern matching I should use ?

Is my design flawed in the first place ?

I'm using angular `6.0.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HttpRequest](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) has an [`url`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#url) attribute you can use:

```
if (/^\/login$/.test(request.url)) {
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

There is also a [`urlWithParams`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#urlWithParams) if you need the params to make the decision.

Notice that immediately calling [next.handle()](https://angular.io/guide/http#the-next-object) makes your interceptor a noop, and the other interceptors will be executed as if yours was not there.

Comment: Thanks for this code chunk. I understand it is supposed to sit inside the interceptor. Is there any way not to fire the intercetor at all ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible: `HttpClient` uses a chain of interceptors, the first one is executed and it needs to pass the controller to the next one, and the chain starts. So, each interceptor ends up executing in order. Even if your interceptor doesn't have anything to do, the previous interceptor doesn't know about it, so it will still pass control to your interceptor. Now, if your interceptor shouldn't do anything, just invoke `next.handle`, which passes the control to the next interceptor (I updated my answer, noticed I missed calling next.handle previously).